# Check if my query not return entity

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, entity

when i try this:

```
$emGeneral = $this->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');
                    $idequipo= $emGeneral->getRepository('AgcManagerBundle:EquipoControl')
                       ->createQueryBuilder('p')
                       ->where('p.codigo = "'.$i["equipo"].'"')
                       ->getQuery()
                       ->setMaxResults(1000)
                       ->setFirstResult(0)
                       ->getResult();
```

I get the next error:

[2/2] QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 72: Error: Expected Literal, got '"'
[1/2] QueryException: SELECT p FROM Agc\ManagerBundle\Entity\EquipoControl p WHERE p.codigo = "0E150347"

Comment: Please add more information about your problem. It is hard to understand what do you need.

Comment: I need translate this SQL query in a query for my entity.example 
    $query = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT p
    FROM AppBundle:Product p
    WHERE p.price > :price
    ORDER BY p.price ASC'
)->setParameter('price', '19.99');

$products = $query->getResult();
how I check returns something ?

Comment: How do you want translate 1 or 0 to an Entity?

Comment: if my query return values, this query returns 1, else 0

Comment: It is understandable. How you will convert this values to an entity? Or what do you want?

Comment: I want to check my entity return me an object of my entity , because if I do not return , I get the following error: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 33: Error: Expected known function, got """

Comment: Sorry. I can't understand your problem. When you will decorate your question with some informative data you can write to me and I will see your question. Now I really can't understand you.

Comment: ok i will edit my post now

Comment: Have you tried swapping `"` for `'`?

Comment: i dont understand you Jovan Perovic, can you put example please?

Comment: **xurshid29** in his answer even went further and parametrized the query. Take a lot at that ;)

Answer (score 3):

Dont pass an argument to `where` method directly, pass it to `setParameter/Parameters` method, like this:

```
$idequipo= $emGeneral->getRepository('AgcManagerBundle:EquipoControl')
                       ->createQueryBuilder('p')
                       ->where('p.codigo = :equipo')
                       ->setParameter('equipo', $i['equipo'])
                       ->getQuery()
                       ->setMaxResults(1000)
                       ->setFirstResult(0)
                       ->getResult();
```